# Reconnecting to the same published application from different machine

Tags: citrix, xen, xenapp

Reconnecting to the same published application from different machine.

Using XENAPP, Lets say I have published a custom .net application (test.exe) and assume that it provides some mspaint like funcationality such as load an image from disk and modify using the tools provided in test.exe . Lets assume this resides on Server A.

The clients connects to the server A through citrix ICA Session , launches the test.exe and begins to use this application.

If the user decides to log from a different machine, Is it possible to connect to the same session ( knowing that I know the user name, pwd, etc to logon to the same session) , so that I can start to use the application from where I left off ? instead of again launching the test.exe ?

In short I would like to reconnect to the published application from where I left off from differnt machine.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is default functionality in Citrix XenApp. It's called [Workspace Control](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116633). (the link describes Presentation Server 4.0/4.5 but the functionality is the same)

Comment: Thank you. I am using client side development to launch the wcfrun32.exe , create ica file and connect to the xen app server to launch the published application (say test.exe). From a different machine, while connecting to the text.exe, can we check if this process already exists for that user and if yes , load it instead of launching new instance of test.exe.

Comment: By default, XenApp will reconnect you to an existing session. Even though documentation for the ica client object states that workspace control is not supported it does work.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I use cmd client to launch application from machine x - it would be something as below-                  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\Wfica32.exe" C:\someICAfile.ica \Param:"/applicationName= text.exe /username=SomebodysName" /password=Password .               If I issue the same command from different machine y, then it will try to launch another instance of text.exe instead of reconnecting to the existing exe ?   can we specify in command line ( or any other mechanism ) to  reconnect if there is already text.exe running ?

Comment: Use the Ica Client Object instead (http://community.citrix.com/display/xa/ICA+Client+Object+SDK) or use PNAgent.exe (http://xentraveller.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/citrix-pnagent-command-line-switches/)